# how to catch when node is being promoted?

Tags: nodes

I would like to take some action when node is being promoted. I tried using node_validate or node_presave but none of them is working.

What is the quickest way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) ...

Below is the code which works for me... Trick is here you need to make sure if node is new and promoted take action.. If node already promoted that means you are editing a node... You need to check whether original was unpromoted and after edit it is promoted then take action...

```
function YOURMODULENAME_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->is_new && $node->promote == 1) {
    drupal_set_message("NODE PROMOTED");
    // Take Some Action
  }
  else if ($node->promote == 1 && $node->original->promote == 0){
    drupal_set_message("NODE PROMOTED");
    // Take some action
  }
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i tried, but in some cases it's not working, orginal-promote is set to 1. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by some cases.. Please explain... If original promote is set to 1 that means node is already promoted before editing...

Comment: In view, it is shown that node is not promoted. But when i check with dpm($node), promote flag is set to 1.

Comment: Is it cache issue ? Can you try clearing cache ? What do you mean by view ? View created using views module ?

Comment: I tried clearing cache, but it remains the same. Yes, i have created View for viewing unpromoted nodes.

Comment: Are you sure unpromoted not unpublished in your view ? Can you take  your views screenshot of filters and post here ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13367/discussion-between-gregab-and-anil-sagar)

Comment: You should really use the defines: NODE_PROMOTED and NODE_NOT_PROMOTED.